# How do I run a task once after 2 seconds?

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, bukkit

In my plugin, I have a `/duel` command. I have done everything I need apart from one thing. When a player dies, I need the killer to be teleported to spawn after 2 seconds. Here is what my `onPlayerDeath()` looks like.

```
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerDeath(PlayerDeathEvent e) {
    Player p = e.getEntity().getPlayer();
    Player k = e.getEntity().getKiller();
    p.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED  +"[" + ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + "HuntsCraft" + ChatColor.DARK_RED + "]" + ChatColor.RED + " Killed by " + ChatColor.BLUE + k.getName());
    k.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "[" + ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + "HuntsCraft" + ChatColor.DARK_RED + "]"  + ChatColor.GREEN + " You killed " + ChatColor.BLUE + p.getName());
    p.getInventory().clear();
    k.getInventory().clear();
    p.getEquipment().clear();
    k.getEquipment().clear();
    k.setFlying(true);
    Bukkit.broadcastMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "["+  ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + "HuntsCraft" + ChatColor.DARK_RED + "] " + ChatColor.DARK_AQUA + k.getName() + ChatColor.AQUA + " just beat " + ChatColor.DARK_AQUA + p.getName() + ChatColor.AQUA + " in a duel!");
    // Teleport the killer to spawn after 2 seconds
}
```

I have done this before but I have forgotten how to use it.

Comment: You do not need `e.getEntity().getPlayer()` because `e.getEntity()` is already of type `Player`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [Scheduler provided by Bukkit](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Scheduler_Programming).
See also [`World.getSpawnLocation()`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/World.html#getSpawnLocation()).

```
Winner winner = new Winner(k);
/* 
 * The first argument is the unique instance of the main class
 * The second argument is the delay in ticks (1 second = 20 ticks)
 */
winner.runTaskLater(Plugin, 40L);
```

---

```
public class Winner extends BukkitRunnable {
    private Player player;
    public Winner(Player player) {
        this.player = player;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Location spawn = player.getWorld().getSpawnLocation();
        player.teleport(spawn);
    }
}
```

Comment: @MattyFenny I used that variable to represent a generic `Location` object because I do not know how you define the spawn.

Comment: i think it would be

`double x = //coords of x;
double y = //coords of y;
double z = //coords of z;

Location spawn = new Location(player.getWorld(), x, y, z);`

Comment: @MattyFenny Do you want to get the spawn of the world where the player is?

Comment: @MattyFenny See the edit. What do you mean by _It does not work._?

Comment: I tested it out, when a player kills someone, nothing happens other than the message i set to send to them.

Comment: @MattyFenny Maybe the combat log plugin blocks the teleportation?

Comment: i dont have the combat log plugin on my test server.

Comment: None of the code gives errors, its all fine. Everything else works fine other than the teleport after 2 seconds after a kill.

Comment: Wait, in the console when i killed another player, it said 'cannot make player fly if `getAllowFlight()` is false, ill set it to allow and that might fix it.

Comment: nevermind, the error was a line of code that i put in, fixed now and works great! thanks so much!